# Get highcharts chart column position

Tags: highcharts

I have a highcharts chart with a chart type column (unfortunately I'm not able to post images yet)

I need to get position of each column (or point in case of line chart type) on a page (means top, left or something like this). I've tried a lot options, like `this.series.data.PlotX` (and `plotY`), this.plotX etc. Nothing is helpfull. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The `plotX` and `plotY` properties on the point object are indeed the pixel positions of the column or point *but* within the plot.  If you want position in the page you need to factor in the charts `plotLeft` and `plotTop` properties:

```
var plotLeft = Highcharts.charts[0].plotLeft;
var plotTop = Highcharts.charts[0].plotTop;
$.each(Highcharts.charts[0].series,function(i, s){
    $.each(s.points, function(j, p){
        console.log('Series: ' + i +', Point: ' + j + ', Left: ' + (p.plotX + plotLeft) +  ', Top: ' + (p.plotY + plotTop));
    });
});
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n843uak1/2/).